# Get all computed style of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to get all the style applyed to an element e.g like in chrome developer tool you have seen at top right section called "Computed Style" i want to get all the list is there any other simple way to get all the list and property

[Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/cyVMb/)

i tried this javascript but it is not what i want, i have to manual write css property

i just want all the style applied to a element earlier or by default

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: i din't get any solution in that post, so i have created my own

Comment: Looks like this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830517/522877

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this function ([updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/cyVMb/1/));

```
function getComputedStyle(elm, style) {
    var computedStyle;
    if (typeof elm.currentStyle != "undefined") {
        computedStyle = elm.currentStyle;
    }
    else {
        computedStyle = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elm, null);
    }
    return computedStyle[style];
}
```

`getComputedStyle()` function is from [I does Javascript!](http://blog.stchur.com/2006/06/21/css-computed-style/)

Comment: The jQuery `css` function has also implemented this function, including more "hooks" to deal with browser inconsistencies.