# My JavaScript if...else statement isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm fairly new to javascript, and I'm trying to use a simple if...else statement to toggle between showing and hiding a div element.  My HTML page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#fluffy {
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            background-color:yellow;
            display:block;
}
#pepper {
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            background-color:green;
            display:block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fluffy"></div>
<div id="pepper" onclick="changeState()"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeState() {
var divState = document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display;
if (document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display = 'none';
}
else if (document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    alert('test error message');
}
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I load the page in my browser, I receive an alert box containing 'test error message'.  My original code had document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display stored in a variable called divState, but this didn't even give me an alert box, it didn't do anything.  I get the feeling I'm using == wrong or something, but I'm really not sure.  I've used ===, and when that didn't work I switched to ==, which is in the code above.

If anyone knows what exactly I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate the help.

Thanks, Harold

Comment: Do you use Firebug? It is an useable plugin for your browser, which shows you a bug fast always. You can browse all properties or check if some method exists etc. == is the right way to compare strings, I mean. I have similar troubles with storing objects to variables in Javascript. Sometimes, it is the best way dont use it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it looks like you guys fixed my problems.  I can't thank you enough, and I will definitely look into jQuery!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as *Accepted* :)

Answer (score 0):

When the page first loads, the div doesn't have any inline styles. `element.style` reads inline styles only.

You will need to render the div with `style="display:block;"` or if you can't/don't want to do that, look into `getComputedStyle` options for your supported browsers

Comment: But `document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display;` will return the respective right. So he can have it `var divState = document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display;
    if ( divState == 'block') {` This should work right?

Comment: @user1671639 No, as i said above, `.style` only uses *inline styles* that is the `style=""` attribute on the element. The OP can only use this method if `display:block;` is explicitly set on the element before this JS runs

Comment: Oh, I understood.  OP's code will work only with **inline style not in embedded or external styles**.  Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `onclick` to be this

```
<div id="pepper" onclick="changeState"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('fluffy').style.display` is `''`. Since you're setting styles with a stylesheet, you'll have to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) (plus friends for cross-browser compatibility). You can find an example cross-browser implementation in the answer to [Get all computed style of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625855/get-all-computed-style-of-an-element).

Answer (score 0):

Use computed style:

```
<div id="fluffy"></div>
<div id="pepper" onclick="changeState()"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeState() {
    var fluffy = document.getElementById('fluffy');
    var divState = window.getComputedStyle(fluffy).display;

    if (divState == 'block') {
       fluffy.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (divState == 'none') {
       fluffy.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
       alert('test error message');
    }
}
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmZZH/)

Comment: May I suggest using `document.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle()`, because older versions of IE don't support `window.getComputedStyle()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-retrieve-a-styles-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I know, you're trying to learn JavaScript what I also want to encourage, but with [jQuery](http://jquery.com), this  whole stuff would be a one-liner plus crossbrowser-friendly etc.

```
<div id="fluffy"></div>
<div id="pepper"></div>
```

The `<script>` contains just:

```
$("#pepper").click(function () { $("#fluffy").toggle(); });
```

**[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/RrQWV/)** at JSFiddle.

Comment: But `jQuery` is not tagged here.  Maybe he wants to try using pure JS.

Comment: @user1671639 sure, but well what's wrong with showing people some alternative solutions, especially if it looks that they attempt to reinvent the square wheel? ;)