# accessing the content of a class using js

Tags: javascript, class, styles

I need to know the content of a class by using js.
for example :-

```
<p style='visibility:hidden'>hello !</p>
```

if we wrote

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('P')[0].style.visibility)
```

it will returns `"hidden"` , BUT if we wrote

```
<p class='peter'>hello !</p>
<style>.peter{visibility:hidden}</style>
```

it will returns `""`. !!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all computed style of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625855/get-all-computed-style-of-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elem.style` refers to its HTML `style` attribute, not its computed style. So styles that are declared with a `<style></style>` tag or `<link/` tag will be *computed* but they won't affect `elem.style`, as they are not the value of the elements `style` attribute. Only `<sometag style="...">` would affect `elem.style`. To get *computed* style, try using `window.getComputedStyle(elem)`.