# why does the initial state of a div when accessed via javascript has no value?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
      body {
      color: white;
      background-color: #1E1B1B;
      border-color: grey;
      }
      .navbar {
      height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      display: block;
      }
      button.nav-btn {
      float:right;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 12px;
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: left;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
          function toggleToolNav() {
          var dis = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0]
          alert(dis.style.display)
          }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <button class="drop-down-toggle" onclick="toggleToolNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the top left button is pressed, the alert popup box prints nothing indicating that `navbar` has no display. But `navbar` is a `div` element with `display = block` explicitly set in the CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning a value because the `style` attribute does not contain any value in this instance. If for example we move the `display: block` to the element as a `style` attribute like `style="display: block"` then it would return the value as you expect. See example provided, but the behavior is expected.

Hope this helps, cheers!

PS - a `div` is a block element by default, no need to define it in the css unless you're overriding the default for whatever reason.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
      body {
      color: white;
      background-color: #1E1B1B;
      border-color: grey;
      }
      .navbar {
      height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      button.nav-btn {
      float:right;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 12px;
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: left;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
          function toggleToolNav() {
          var dis = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0];
          console.log(dis);
          alert(dis.style.display);
          }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar" style="display: block">
      <button class="drop-down-toggle" onclick="toggleToolNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but since it is a `div` element doesn't it by default have a display of block?

Comment: @ganidat - correct, that's why I had that observation in the "PS" note right before the snippet ;)

Comment: so why does the alert not print out block then?

Comment: Because your alert is looking for the value of the [style attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp) which is not present on the element in your example. If you want the "computed styles" of an element than you need to query that element differently by [requesting the computed styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625855/get-all-computed-style-of-an-element).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to get the CSS computedStyle. You can use getComputedStyle to return an object containing the values of all CSS properties of said element.

```css
getComputedStyle(dis, "display").display
```

Will return the display rule set in your elements css. As Chris W explained in the prior answer if you use `el.style.display`, it is looking for the inline style rule for display.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
      body {
      color: white;
      background-color: #1E1B1B;
      border-color: grey;
      }
      .navbar {
      height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      display: block;
      }
      button.nav-btn {
      float:right;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 12px;
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: left;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
          function toggleToolNav() {
          var dis = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0]
          alert(getComputedStyle(dis, "display").display)
          }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <button class="drop-down-toggle" onclick="toggleToolNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```